# Regex for capturing specific values in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I trying to get the values from a string by a regular expression pattern,
it works, but it will return all matched strings (I mean the string with `{}` too)

this is the string:

```
dashboard/admin/{content}/category/{category}/posts
```

Regex pattern:

```
/{(.*?)}/
```

and the PHP code is :

```
    preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $url, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

and the content of `$matches` is:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "{content}"
    1 => "content"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => "{category}"
    1 => "category"
  ]
]
```

but I want to have an array  like this:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "content",
  1 => "category"
]
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Just iterate over the matches and select `$match[1]` will do the trick to transform your actual result to the desired one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookaround:

```
$url = 'dashboard/admin/{content}/category/{category}/posts';
preg_match_all('/(?<={).*?(?=})/', $url, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => category
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `PREG_SET_ORDER` so that the index's are by capture group.

```
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', 'dashboard/admin/{content}/category/{category}/posts', $matches);
```

with this use `$matches[1]`, because `1` will be the first capture group. The `0` index will be all full matches.

Comment: it shows me exactly that result :(

Comment: `print_r($matches[1])` => `Array ( [0] => content [1] => category )` it shows to me @MajAfy.

Comment: @MajAfy Not sure what you mean. This is exactly what you asked for. All matches under 1 index. https://3v4l.org/kdBQH, or the `I want to have an array like this` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `\K` and a single positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is a `}`:

```
{\K[^}]+(?=})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r8YNaI/1)

```
$url = 'dashboard/admin/{content}/category/{category}/posts';
preg_match_all('/{\K[^}]+(?=})/', $url, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => content
    [1] => category
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/qPDCg)